# How to arrange nodes in "horizontal tree layout"?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I've been using draw.io's "horizontal tree layout" feature but I'm having an ordering issue after I've inserted the horizontal tree. For example:

In the navigation, I select *Arrange* → *Insert* → *Horizontal tree*, then I build my tree as expected and insert into application. Afterwards, I want to edit the tree by inserting another node at one of the top parts, then re-arrange it by selecting all then *Arrange* → *Layout* → *Horizontal flow*, but when I do this the node that I inserted appears at the bottom of the tree instead of where I want it to go.

Is there a way to place the node exactly where I want it to go? How can I properly order them so they will "auto arrange" correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The flow and tree are different layouts. If your graph is strictly a tree, then layout as a tree, not a flow. The flow is only needed when you have a directed graph, just not a tree (i.e. each child doesn't have exactly one parent).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me with automatic arrangements for flows.

From the menu bar :

```
Arrange > Layout > Horizontal Tree

Arrange > Layout > Horizontal Flow

Arrange > Layout > Vertical Tree

Arrange > Layout > Vertical Flow
```

Reference :

https://drawio-app.com/automatic-layout-in-draw-io